# Using AND in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to sum the values in column B when column A is a multiple of 2 and less than 10.

If I use `AND(` in the if this gives a #N/A.

`=sum(filter(B:B,and(MOD(A:A,2)=0,VALUE(A:A)<10)))`

The formulas work individually:

`=sum(filter(B:B,VALUE(A:A)<10))`
`=sum(filter(B:B,MOD(A:A,2)=0))`

This works but it's inelegant with nested if's and array formula:

`=arrayformula(SUM(IF(MOD(A:A,2)=0,IF(VALUE(A:A)<10,B:B,0))))`

I have also tried using `=sumif(` but I couldn't get it to work

Do you know of a way to do this better?

edit:
Sorry I had to update my question to make it clear that I required two separate logical operations in the check.
Thank you Tom Sharp for telling me about `=sum(filter(`

[Example Data on Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fSgsUJbdpGM89SspmpUeJKS3qUWAKPOMIuIlzGj4fvQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this the same as saying column A must be a multiple of 6?

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
=sum(filter(B:B,mod(A:A,6)=0))
```

But if the mod 2 and mod 3 were just examples and I took them too literally, you can combine conditions as follows

```
=sum(filter(B:B,mod(A:A,2)=0,mod(A:A,3)=0))
```

@Max Makhrov is right that the formula in your original post would actually be equivalent to

```
=sum(filter(B:B,mod(A:A,2)=0,mod(A:A,3)<>0))
```

matching even numbers not multiples of three, i.e. 2,4,8,10....

For your new example, you don't put the AND in because it's already implied that each condition in the filter is ANDed with the other conditions. AND doesn't work in this sort of context (it tries to AND all the elements together instead of treating them as two arrays). So it should be

```
=sum(filter(B:B,MOD(A:A,2)=0,VALUE(A:A)<10))
```

but the VALUE shouldn't be necessary unless some of the numbers are formatted as text so it would be

```
=sum(filter(B:B,MOD(A:A,2)=0,A:A<10))
```

If you wanted to get your original array formula working, you would need to replace AND by * . This works because TRUE equates to a value of 1 and FALSE to a value of 0 when they are used in arithmetic expressions

```
=arrayformula(SUM((MOD(A2:A,2)=0)*(VALUE(A2:A)<10)*B2:B,0))
```

Comment: This formula do what OP asked: **sum the values in column B when column A is a multiple of 2 and of 3.**  But OP's formula do another: `=arrayformula(SUM(IF(MOD(A:A,2)=0,IF(MOD(A:A,3),B:B,0))))` sums values when `MOD(A:A,2)=0` and `MOD(A:A,3) <> 0`. I suggest accepting this answer or ask @tom-banister to show an example of data and desired result.

Comment: This is much more elegant than my original array-formula.
Although I realise I chose a bad example using mod 3 and mod 2 as that's equivalent to mod 6 so I am going to change my question.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clear that I require two separate functions which would require some sort of `and` or nested `if`